# R Shiny selecting multiple variables with one checkbox

Tags: r, shiny

Completely new to shiny and I'm just trying to get my head around it's crazy potential.

To give some background, I'm trying to develop an interactive datatable for a shiny app displaying research data. However, my dataset has more than 1000 variables, which obviously can't all be displayed for checkbox selection. To address this I've developed variable groups.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get my head around selecting multiple variables with just one checkbox, then having all those variables (within the selected variable group) displayed in the datatable. Is this even possible? The code below clearly doesn't work, but it's just to give an idea of what I'm trying to do. If someone can point me in the right direction, I'd be really grateful.

Cheers

```
ui <- fluidPage(
checkboxGroupInput("variable", "Variables to show:",
                 c("Cy_Trans_Gear" = c("cyl", "am", "gear"),
                   "Transmission" = "am",
                   "Gears" = "gear")),
tableOutput("data")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
output$data <- renderTable({
mtcars[, c("mpg", input$variable), drop = FALSE]
}, rownames = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Maybe with a [tree](https://trestletech.shinyapps.io/st-03-checkbox/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this would be to create a function that takes in the value from the input and spits out thee required columns (kind of like a look up table). Once you have this, you can filter out the required columns inside and `renderTable({)}` before displaying the table.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
checkboxGroupInput("variable", "Variables to show:",
                 c("Cy_Trans_Gear" = c("cyl", "am", "gear"),
                   "Transmission" = "am",
                   "Gears" = "gear")),
tableOutput("data")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


# Use an ifelse/switch statement
# to return a list of list names
# based on input.

lookupTable <- function(ip) {

        if (ip == "something") {
            return (c("col1", "col2", "col3"))
        } else if () {
            ...
        }        
}

output$data <- renderTable({
selected_column_list <- lookupTable(input$variable)
mtcars %>%
    select(selected_column_list)
}, rownames = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

You can also use base R instead of dplyr to return the table. I haven't tested the code above, so, there might be syntax issues with it but the idea remains.